# kill processes shown by sudo fuser filtered by COMMAND column

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, gpu, fuser

using the following line I have been able to see processes that use the GPU some of which are mentioned python under the COMMAND column.

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
```

which prints:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/nvidia0:        root       1197 F...m Xorg
                     alireza    1451 F...m gnome-shell
                     alireza    5527 F...m python
                     alireza    5567 F.... python
                     alireza    5568 F.... python
```

how can I kill all the processes which are mentiond python in the COMMAND collumn. But so far i have to do it manually by for each PID by `sudo kill -9 <pid>` which is not easy if there are many of them.

is there a way to automate this and make it faster? like writing only one command and kill all the PIDs that has pyton in the COMMAND column?

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `fuser`, maybe `sudo fuser -ikv /dev/nvidia*` would work? This would ask you before killing each process accessing /dev/nvidia*.

Comment: @SamuelDiebolt but would this allow allow to only kill the python ones that are noted in the COMMAND column?

Comment: I can't really test the command on my side, but it should ask you if you want to kill one by one each process associated with the /dev/nvidia* hardware files. In your case, it would be: "Kill Xorg? n; Kill gnome-shell? n; Kill python? y; ...". Far from perfect, but still a bit faster than typing each PID one by one.

Comment: I just tested `sudo fuser -ikv /dev/null` on my machine, it works as I described: the list of processes associated with the given file/socket is displayed and a prompt asks you  if you want to kill each process one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here is a one-liner that should kill all python processes using `/dev/nvidia*`:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia* 2>&1 | grep python | grep -o -E " [0-9]+ " | xargs kill
```

The `2>&1` redirection is necessary because of how `fuser` outputs its results. `grep python` will select all lines contain `python`, then `grep -o -E " [0-9]+ "` will extract the PIDs and `xargs kill` will kill all of them.

Please run `sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia* 2>&1 | grep python` first to verify if no unwanted processes were selected by mistake.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The following command will display processes using the hardware files `/dev/nvidia*` and a prompt will ask you if you want to kill them one by one:

```
$ sudo fuser -ikv /dev/nvidia*

                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/nvidia0:        root       1197 F...m Xorg
                     alireza    1451 F...m gnome-shell
                     alireza    5527 F...m python
                     alireza    5567 F.... python
                     alireza    5568 F.... python
Kill process 1191 ? (y/N) N
Kill process 1451 ? (y/N) N
Kill process 5527 ? (y/N) y
...
```

This isn't a one-liner that kills all python commands (should be possible using `fuser | grep | cut | kill`), but it is faster than typing each PID by hand.

Comment: worked as expected:) I just also added a -9 in the end. thanks